# How to split a string of array of arrays of integers into List<int[]>?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I serialized a javascript array using JSON.stringify and got a string which I used it as:

```
string test = "[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]";
```

How do I convert 'test' to a C# List variable?

Comment: Maybe you need a parser or some sort of string manipulation algorithm.

Comment: Can you use [Json.Net](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/107620) and deserialize it?

Comment: Is it in `List<int[]>` or `List<int,int>`?

Comment: @Christian Read the title!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic `JavaScriptSerializer` works for this:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

string test = "[[0,2],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]";

var listOfInts = new JavaScriptSerializer()
                     .Deserialize<int[][]>(test)
                     .SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

var listOfArrays = new JavaScriptSerializer()
                       .Deserialize<int[][]>(test)
                       .Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Not sure whether you wanted a list of arrays or a straight up list of each number.. so I gave both.